# How does manual backup/restore of TFS server work?

Tags: tfs

I setup TFS 2013 Express on my dev PC.

The only backup method that I can do is a manual backup.

These are the steps that I did:

1. I backed up the TFS Team Project DB and the TFS Configuration DB.
2. I added a comment to my code and checked it in.
3. I restored the backup db's from step one using TFSRestore.exe
4. I deleted the source code from my PC and did a get latest.
5. I noticed that my comment from step 2 was still present.

When I restore a TFS database shouldn't I loose the changes that were made after the given backup?

EDIT:

I ran a second test and this time I made sure:
[image]

I still had the same results.

Comment: Do you stop team project collection when you backup DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you backup database, make sure you have stopped the team project collection. 
Also, before restore, try to delete existing database that will restore.

Comment: That was it. Thanks